# How can I justify a Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

here is my code for what I want get Justified, how could I do that?

my goal:

[image]

curent issue:

[image]

the code:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var stringOfText: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {

        Text(stringOfText).font(Font.body.bold()).padding()
 
        Button("Justiy it!") {

            stringOfText = Array(2...100).reduce("1", ({$0 + " " + String($1)}))
            
        }
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that natively. You have the `.multilineTextAlignment(.center)` modifier that you can apply some alignments to your text, but there is no justify option.

[Apple Documentation on `multilineTextAlignment(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/multilinetextalignment(_:))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a monospaced font for this, here is a example with `Courier`.

```
Text(
  (1...100).map { $0.description }.joined(separator: " ")
).font(Font.custom("Courier", size: 17))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! But it won't work if you change the font size.

Comment: @HarshilPatel it will work with different font size, you can have a try yourself.

Comment: @JIEWANG:  thanks for you trying, but I did not want change the font! also I want work with stringOfText. you chopped out my codes to reach an answer!

Comment: @HarshilPatel I see, 